# Show local images in React-Native NativeBase

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

It works if I show the image like this:

```
<Thumbnail source= {require('../images/01.jpg')} />
```

But fails on :

```
<Thumbnail source= {require('../images/'+ {person.id} +'.jpg')} />
```

`person.id` comes from an array of `people`. Printing it in `<Text>{person.id}</Text>` gives the output as `01` or `02`.

How to show a local image with the name as the prop.value?

I tried:

```
<Thumbnail source= {require(`../images/${person.id}.jpg`)} />
```

and

```
<Thumbnail source= {require('../images/'+ person.id +'.jpg')} />
```

Both fails with error : Unnamed named module: '../images/1.jpg'
[image]

Comment: Is that image that you are trying to require available before packaging an application? I mean like when that image is for example set by user at runtime, then require won't work and you need to use <Thumbnail source={{ uri: 'file://path/to/saved/image' }} />. Check this discussion here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391.

Comment: All the images are already in the images folder and i repacked the app a few times

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not really possible.

Packaging happens once **before runtime** so the variable `person.id` doesn't have value yet.

This has already been discussed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391).

In the discussion you can see solutions to this problem.

Basically you need to **import all possible files** you are going to use.

**Simple approach:**

```
var firstImage = require('../images/01.jpg');
var secondImage =  require('../images/02.jpg');  
var myComponent = (whichImageToUse) ? firstComponent : secondComponent;
```

**Sophisticated approach:** Create a file which requires all images.

**allImages.js**

```
export default {
    '01': require('../images/01.jpg'),
    '02': require('../images/02.jpg'),
    // import all other images
}
```

Import that file where you need to use an image and access the individual image like this:

```
import images from '../images/allImages'
<Thumbnail source={images[person.id]} />
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted this for testing. Works like a charm. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you remove the curly brackets from person.id:

```
<Thumbnail source= {require('../images/'+ {person.id} +'.jpg')} />
```

Like this:

```
<Thumbnail source= {require('../images/'+ person.id +'.jpg')} />
```

or this (using es6 template literals):

```
<Thumbnail source= {require(`../images/${person.id}.jpg`)} />
```

Comment: Thanks. For both  I get an error: Error: Unnamed named module: '../images/1.jpg' Edited the question and added the error.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing component of NativeBase Thumbnail is React-Native's Image.

If you achieve this with React Native Image and not with NativeBase Thumbnail then thats an issue with NativeBase.

This issue has already been discussed in the issues of React Native

[#2481](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481), [#6391](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391), [#10290](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10290)

Comment: Thank you @Supriya .. I followed Patrick's suggestion and it works.